# the Almost Feedback Vertex Set problam

Tags: algorithms, graphs

**the problem:**
In Almost Feedback Vertex Set, we are given an undirected graph G and k ∈ N, and the
objective is to decide whether there exists a subset S ⊆ V (G) of size at most k such that every
connected component in G − S is either a tree or a cycle.

Design a  (4^k)*n^O(1)-time algorithm for Almost Feedback Vertex Set.
and Design a ((7/4)^n)*n^O(1)-time algorithm for Almost Feedback Vertex Set.

i try to use sampling method but didn't succeed to design the algorithem :)

Comment: Curiously this seems to be exactly the question here too: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68141645/solving-the-almost-feedback-vertex-set-problem

Comment: oh yes :)but no sol ther :/

Comment: Please credit the original source of all copied material: https://cs.stackexchange.com/help/referencing

Comment: Please ask only one question per post.  If you have multiple questions, they can be asked separately.

Comment: What did you try? Where did you get stuck? We're happy to help you understand the concepts but just solving exercises for you is unlikely to achieve that. You might find [this page](https://cs.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1284/755) helpful in improving your question.